# Formatting integer while binding to label

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, data-binding, number-formatting

I am trying to format an integer while binding it to the text property of a label.

I know I can use setText() in my value setter, but I'd rather do it the proper way through binding.

In my controller initialization I had:

```
sec = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this,"seconds");
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.convert(sec));
```

But when the number of seconds dropped below 10, it showed as a single digit, but I want it to stay as two digits. So I tried changing the Binding to the following:

```
 secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
        formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
        if(sec.getValue() == null) {
            return "";
        }else {
            return formatter.format(sec.get());
        }
    }));
```

This will format it, but when I overwrite it `sec.set(newNumber);` the value doesn't change.

I also tried this:

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if(sec.getValue() == null) {
                return "";
            }else {
                return String.format("%02d", sec.getValue());
            }
        }));
```

But that did the same thing. Loads up fine, shows two digits, but when the number was changed via `sec.set(newNumber);` nothing changed. The number will never go higher than sixty or lower than zero

Comment: I just tried putting it in its own instance but the same thing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your binding that it should be invalidated any time the `sec` property is invalidated. `Bindings.createStringBinding(...)` takes a varargs parameter after the function that should be passed any properties to which the binding needs to bind. You can directly adapt your code as follows:

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
    if(sec.getValue() == null) {
        return "";
    }else {
        return formatter.format(sec.get());
    }
}, sec));
```

or

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    if(sec.getValue() == null) {
        return "";
    }else {
        return String.format("%02d", sec.getValue());
    }
}, sec));
```

As @fabian points out, `IntegerProperty.get()` never returns null, so you can remove the null check and just do:

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> String.format("%02d", sec.getValue()),
    sec));
```

and there is a convenience version of this in the bindings API:

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%02d", sec));
```

Comment: That makes sense, and I just tried it and it works great! Thanks

Comment: The check for `null` is unnecessary since a `IntegerProperty` is used and any attempt to set the value to `null` results in the value in the property becoming `0`.

Comment: @fabian Yes: that what comes of blindly copying code from the OP. Added that info into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

IntegerProperty inherits a lot of useful methods, including [asString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString-java.lang.String-):

```
secondsLabel.textProperty().bind(sec.asString("%02d"));
```